# How to I do a INNER JOIN and WHERE, from second table, on a Django Model and return the JSON?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Trying to use the Django models and do a INNER JOIN on a specific column and then doing a WHERE on a column which is in the second table.

I want the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM Songs INNER JOIN Artists ON Songs.PageURL = Artists.PageURL WHERE IsSingle = 1 AND Artist like 'Singer%' ORDER BY Entry_At DESC
```

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Artists(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(db_column='Artist', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pageurl = models.CharField(db_column='PageURL', primary_key=True, max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    albumurl = models.CharField(db_column='AlbumURL', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Artists'
        unique_together = (('pageurl', 'artist'),)


class Lyrics(models.Model):
    lyrics = models.CharField(db_column='Lyrics', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pageurl = models.CharField(db_column='PageURL', primary_key=True, max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    albumurl = models.CharField(db_column='AlbumURL', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Lyrics'
        unique_together = (('pageurl', 'lyrics'),)


class Music(models.Model):
    music = models.CharField(db_column='Music', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pageurl = models.CharField(db_column='PageURL', primary_key=True, max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    albumurl = models.CharField(db_column='AlbumURL', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Music'
        unique_together = (('pageurl', 'music'),)


class Songs(models.Model):
    index = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    entry_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Entry_At')  # Field name made lowercase.
    issingle = models.IntegerField(db_column='IsSingle')  # Field name made lowercase.
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    album = models.CharField(db_column='Album', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    label = models.CharField(db_column='Label', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    release_date = models.CharField(db_column='Release_Date', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    code = models.CharField(db_column='Code', unique=True, max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    link_320 = models.CharField(db_column='Link_320', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    link_128 = models.CharField(db_column='Link_128', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    link_48 = models.CharField(db_column='Link_48', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    imageurl = models.CharField(db_column='ImageURL', max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pageurl = models.CharField(db_column='PageURL', primary_key=True, max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.
    albumurl = models.CharField(db_column='AlbumURL', max_length=400)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Songs'
```

I have seen options with filter, select_related and others. But I have not been able to get them working or get the specific query I need from above.

Comment: how did you define forginkey relation?

Comment: I don't believe my table has foreign key relation. The PageURL is the key that is in all tables which is unique to all rows. I use that to match and get data through SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices. First you can execute a raw SQL statement against your database.  I know that's not what you want, but you could do that.

Sometimes I find that I get better performance because I can write just the one SQL statement using raw SQL rather than using the current record approach and I quite like having the control.

Second if you want to use the ORM then you will need to tell the ORM how your tables are related.  You will need to set foreign keys so the ORM can do the joins for you. see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/) then you can do select_related or you can filter with ...objects.filter(songs__artists__etc)